# Display post order ranking within wordpress loop

Tags: posts, theme-development, loop, get-template-part

I am trying to display the numerical post order ranking on the home page, however, I am using template_parts and am not aware of how to do this when the html is separated from the wordpress loop.

Here's what I want to see:

[image: ranking concept]

Here is my loop in `index.php`

```
<div class="most-recent-feed">
    <?php
    if ( have_posts() ) :
        if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) : ?>
        <header>
            <h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
        </header>
        <?php
        endif;
        $post_ranking = 1;
        /* Start the Loop */
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            ?> <h1> <?php echo $post_ranking ?> </h1> <?php
            /*
             * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
             * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
             * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
             */
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
        endwhile;
        the_posts_navigation();
    else :
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
    endif; 
wp_reset_query();

?>
</div>
```

And here is my relevant html in `template_parts/content.php` (note the comment where the ranking number should be placed:

```
<div class="album-dark-overlay play">
    <div class="ranking-triangle">
    <!-- Ranking number should be placed here -->
    </div>
    <div id="<?php echo $youtube_id ?>" data-youtube-id="<?php echo $youtube_id ?>" class="media-circle">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-play"></i><i class="icon ion-pause"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not straightforward to pass a variable to a template part. However, when you are in a loop, WP has [a counter called `current_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties) that you can use in this way in your template part:

```
global $post;
$ranking = $post->$current_post + 1; // +1 because the counter starts at 0
```

Comment: I guess I'm just sort of confused on how I'm able to relate this $ranking variable that is initialized in my `index.php` to the html that is found in `content.php` @cjbj

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways I suggest you do that:

- You can store the post rankings in your database `wp_postmeta` or any table of your choice, and then retrieve the value via `WP_QUERY` or any of your choice, which will then be `echoed` in your desired location.

**OR**

- You can use `PHP for` loop. Get the length of the posts `(posts_per_page)` and then iterate through each of your result, which will then echo the ranking based on the first-second-third-fourth etc.

Here's an example:

```
// Get the length of the items (which is determined by the number you enter in 'posts_per_page'
$loop_length = 6 // using this as an example
for( $i = 0; $i <= $loop_length; $i++ ) {
  echo $i;
}
// Your result will be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.
```

Hope this helps.